# How can I make the text in the <p> tag not wrap and hide its overflow?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

Using tailwindcss, how can I make the first `<p>` child truncate (or at least have hidden overflow) as its container shrinks? Nothing that I do makes this work. The text always wraps even if I specify `whitespace-nowrap`, `overflow-hidden` or any other class.

The flex boxes themselves behave correctly. The first text shrinks and the second remains the same size as the `inner-fb-one` and `inner-fb-two` flex boxes shrink. The only thing that I cannot get to work is the text to **not wrap and hide the overflow**.

To c

```js
    <div className='flex flex-row ml-3 space-y-1 items-end border' id='container-fb'>
      <div className='flex flex-row items-center' id='inner-fb-one'>
        <p className='whitespace-nowrap'>truncate this first child as the container shrinks</p>
        <p className='shrink-0'>keep this the same size</p>
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-row items-center' id='inner-fb-two'>
        <p className='whitespace-nowrap'>truncate this first child as the container shrinks</p>
        <p className='shrink-0'>keep this the same size</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className='flex flex-row ml-3 space-y-1 items-end border' id='container-fb'>
  <div className='flex flex-row items-center' id='inner-fb-one'>
    <p className='whitespace-nowrap text-overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden w-full'>
      truncate this first child as the container shrinks
    </p>
    <p className='shrink-0'>keep this the same size</p>
  </div>
  <div className='flex flex-row items-center' id='inner-fb-two'>
    <p className='whitespace-nowrap text-overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden w-full'>
      truncate this first child as the container shrinks
    </p>
    <p className='shrink-0'>keep this the same size</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the text in a `<p>` tag from wrapping and hiding its overflow, you can use the white-space: nowrap CSS property. Here's an example:

```
<p style="white-space: nowrap;">This is some text that will not wrap and will hide its overflow.</p>
```

If you want to apply this style to multiple elements, you can define a CSS class and apply it to the `<p>` tags:

```
.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<p class="no-wrap">This is some text that will not wrap and will hide its overflow.</p>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `overflow: hidden` property to hide the overflow, like this:

```
<p style="overflow: hidden;">This is some text that will not wrap and will hide its overflow.</p>
```

You can combine these two properties to achieve the desired effect, like this:

```
<p style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
  This is some text that will not wrap and will hide its overflow.
</p>
```